# How to define a function with same name which is present in different file

Tags: c++

I want to define a class like this

```
class HttpRestAccessor
{
public:
    IResource& UpdateResource(string& , IResource& );
};
```

and implementing in cpp file

```
IResource& HttpRestAccessor::UpdateResource(string& resourceUri, IResource& resource)
```

this cpp file refers to Winbase.h which has defined UpdateResource as follows

```
#define UpdateResource  UpdateResourceW
```

And hence while compiling i get following error

error C2039: 'UpdateResourceW' : is not a member of 'RestToolkit::HttpRestAccessor'

this problem would be solved if rename function name to something different. 
but I would love to keep my function name as UpdateResource.

Thanks In Advance,
Uday

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Macro's totally ignore scope.

Basically the pre-precessor will do a find/replace of UpdateResource with UpdateResourceW so you're all out of luck.

renaming the method is your only option

Comment: +1 for renaming the method. The simplest and quickest way to solve the problem without "hacks"

Comment: It's flat wrong to say renaming is the only option.  Maybe the only non-hack option, but not the only option.

Answer (score 5):

Just undefine it:

```
 #undef UpdateResource
```

then redefine later if you actually need it.

EDIT: However, you should reconsider your aversion to renaming the method.  As others have said, that's a more elegant solution.

Comment: This will have to be done prior to each inclusion of winbase.h which is not always done directly. Lots of pain.

Comment: Create function, winbasewrap.h, which does the undef and include.  Find and replace your includes with this one.

Comment: I'm down voting this answer (specifically due to it's current success).  Yes this will work but it's a particularly stinky "code smell".  It's one of those clever tricks which over time will be forgotten until some poor maintainer spends 5 days trying to work out why code which used to compile no longer does.

Comment: Richard, I wrote this answer because the OP specifically said "I would love to keep my function name as UpdateResource."  I personally would prefer changing the name.

Comment: @Matthew: Ok, I can see now why you did this. However, I still think you're doing a disservice to the OP in this case. The solution is a huge hack for what has a much more sensible solution. I think providing answers that cover the question 100% should be secondary to providing answers that will reflect the "best solution". Given that you agreed with the renaming idea, maybe you could add a comment to your answer like: "this should only be used where renaming is simply not an option, rather than not desirable".  BTW, I cannot return your vote, unless you edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to include winbase.h before all other headers (in stdafx.h) so that you don't care whether the method name is replaced.

Comment: no, no, no.  Any unfortunate user of this class would then end up with the same problem, even if they don't use winbase.h

Answer (score 1):

Rename your function. If you want to use windows libraries then you have to accept they take precedence, you'd never try to create a class called std::string would you?

Comment: std::string is a class conveniently placed in a namespace, which application code doesn't need or want to change, and which doesn't affect anything outside the namespace. "#define UpdateResource  UpdateResourceW" is a nasty hack which ... spits ... all over application code. It's perfectly reasonable for the implementation to reserve the "std" namespace (as stated in the C++ standard). It's plain rude to reserve the symbol "UpdateResource" in all uses.

Comment: @onebyone: I agree completely however if you are going to use windows libraries you have to accept that they take precedence no matter how badly written they may be.

Comment: Yep, if the function is for Windows only then I agree with your answer, just change the name. The problem really bites when you're trying to write portable libraries. Then renaming the function is not a good option, just because Windows clients get a crazy macro along with their Windows environment that stops them calling your perfectly good function. In that situation you want a workaround to use on Windows only, and that's why I think the situation isn't really comparable to std::string.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, that is the evil of the preprocessor!

Answer (score 0):

you could use the #undef preprocessor directive to undefine the UpdateResource macro before you declare you function.

Comment: Will work, but this needs to be done every time winbase.h is included (which is not always done directly) so it will be a lot of pain.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to document that *if* Winbase.h is included, it must be included before this header. Normally that would be a horrible requirement, but with Windows headers, it's pretty much a given that you're in for a world of pain unless you include them first (normally in a precompiled header, as @sharptooth says).

That done, put this in your header:

```
#ifdef UpdateResource
#pragma push_macro("UpdateResource")
#undef UpdateResource
#endif
```

Anyone simultaneously needing the original definition of `UpdateResource` and your class just needs to put

```
#pragma pop_macro("UpdateResource")
```

Answer (score -2):

Namespace is the way to go.